# Point Mahout to HDFS instead of local disk

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, mahout

I am trying to run a logistic regression on Mahout with a file that's in HDFS - the name of the file is ppeng.txt with the following command line.

> mahout org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.TrainLogistic --passes 5
>   --rate 1 --lambda 0.5 --input ppeng.txt --features 21 --output test_mahout --target nbr_of_txns --categories 2 --predictors
>   lifetime_rev_usd_amt ntpv_12_mth_sent_usd_amt --types n n

This file is in HDFS, but, this line errors out with a File Not Found exception unless I copy the file to my local machine.

My HADOOP_LOCAL variable is set to null as well. The error that I get is as follows - has anybody have experience fixing this problem - if so, please help.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ppeng.txt (No such file or directory)**
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.TrainLogistic.open(TrainLogistic.java:316)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.TrainLogistic.mainToOutput(TrainLogistic.java:75)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.TrainLogistic.main(TrainLogistic.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
        at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:188)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is accessing your local file system with java.io.FileInputStream.open.

Can you run

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

from where you are running the Mahout job? If so you need to unset MAHOUT_LOCAL and try again. Mahout uses the Hadoop setup on the machine you are launching from to determine where HDFS and the mapreduce job trackers are.

Here's a post about switching between client, local pseudo cluster, and full cluster membership on a single machine. It also set the right flag for Mahout. Just some bash functions.

http://occamsmachete.com/ml/2012/07/02/how-to-switch-hadoop-confugurations/